# Need help in integrating Scandit barcode scanner in React Native project

Tags: android, ios, react-native, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to integrate a Scandit barcode scanning SDK in React Native project.

The SDK is available for iOS and Android, but I didn't get the SDK for React-Native.

I have downloaded the test Scandit barcode scanner SDK for iOS and Android.

I tried with integrating the iOS SDK framework into Xcode, but I'm not able to link it with React Native.

I have tried with the following links:
http://docs.scandit.com/4.14/ios/ios-integrate.html
https://github.com/nicolaiwolko/RCTScanditBarcodeScanner

followed the steps given on the repo. But, I'm getting blank screen only, I'm new to react-native and not sure what I'm missing.

Looking forward to your help...

Answer (score 1):

Scandit now supports ReactNative officially (since version 5.5): https://github.com/Scandit/barcodescanner-sdk-react-native

Comment: link is 404. I've also been having issues with it and can't find tutorials anywhere. Their v5 docs have all been deprecated, and v6 docs doesn't show any good react-native tutorials. I did see the usage of class components(which have also been deprecated with react). I'm wondering if they are updating their docs code at all...